# I have issue displaying data to a website(laravel project)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Here is my anything.blade.php code:

```
@foreach ($data2 as $value2)
<p class="card-text" id="des6"> {{$value2->description}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Below is how I pass data from the controller

```
public function getHalls(Request $request)
    {

        $data['data'] =\DB::table('advertisements')
            ->select(\DB::raw("*"))
            ->orderBy('idadd')->paginate(12);



         try{
                $data2['data2'] =\DB::table('hotel')
            ->select(\DB::raw("*"))
            ->where('idhotel', '=', '1')
            ->get();
            }catch (QueryException $exception){
            return $exception->getMessage();

            // abort(404, 'The requested resource could not be found.');
            }

        if(count($data['data'])>0)
        {
            return view('hotelpage', $data,$data2);
        }
        else
        {
            return  "no data"; 
        }

    }
}
```

Below is how I get the output

[image: Preview of output]

But I want to display it like below

**fdfd dsfdfdf** fbfbfbf fvbhf

- List item
- List item

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
   @foreach ($data2 as $value2)
               <p class="card-text" id="des6">
                        {!! $value2->description !!}
               </p>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: @NiranPeiris You should note that this exposes you to malicious data in the description. Google "XSS" for examples of how this can be a problem.